# how to use the def function

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am new to python so i hope you guys can help me out. Currently i am using the import function to get my output, but i wish to include def function to this set of code that count the top 10 most frequent word. But i can't figure it out. Hope you guys can help me. Thanks in advance!!!

```
import collections
import re
file = open('partA', 'r')
file = file.read()
stopwords = set(line.strip() for line in open('stopwords.txt'))
stopwords = stopwords.union(set(['it', 'is']))
wordcount = collections.defaultdict(int)
"""
the next paragraph does all the counting and is the main point of difference from the original article. More on this is explained later.
"""
pattern = r"\W"
for word in file.lower().split():
    word = re.sub(pattern, '', word)
    if word not in stopwords:
        wordcount[word] += 1

to_print = int(input("How many top words do you wish to print?"))
print(f"The most common {to_print} words are:")

mc = sorted(wordcount.items(), key=lambda k_v: k_v[1], reverse=True) [:to_print]
for word, count in mc:
    print(word, ":", count)
```

The output:
How many top words do you wish to print?30
The most common 30 words are:
hey : 1
there : 1
this : 1
joey : 1
how : 1
going : 1

Comment: What do you mean by “use the import function” and “use the def function”? Neither of those are functions, they’re statements. And they do very different things: one makes a module and all of its globals available to your code; the other creates a new function.

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp

Answer (score 0):

'def' is used to create a user defined function to later call in a script. For example:

```
def printme(str):
    print(str)


printme('Hello')
```

I've now created a function called 'printme' that I call later to print the string. This is obviously a pointless function as it just does what the 'print' function does, but I hope this clears up what the purpose of 'def' is!